# Linked list implementation in C(printing only last two nodes)

Tags: c, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
void addLast(struct node **head, int value);
void printAll(struct node *head);
struct node *head1 = NULL;

int main() {
    addLast(&head1, 10);
    addLast(&head1, 20);
    addLast(&head1, 30);
    addLast(&head1, 40);    

    printAll(head1);

    return 0;
}

void addLast(struct node **head, int value) {
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = value;
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newNode;
        (*head)->next = NULL; 
    } else {
        struct node **temp = head;

        while ((*temp)->next != NULL) {
            *temp = (*temp)->next;
        }
        (*temp)->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
   }
}

void printAll(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d->", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

`addLast()` will append the new node at the end of the list, with `printAll()`, I am printing entire list.

Every time when I am printing the list, I can only see the last two nodes.

Can anyone please help, why loop is not iterating over entire list ?

Comment: `*temp = (*temp)->next;` : Destructively change the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `addLast` is too complicated and as result is wrong due to this statement

```
*temp = (*temp)->next;
```

in the while loop. It always changes the head node.

Define the function the following way

```
int addLast( struct node **head, int value )
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newNode->data = value;
        newNode->next = NULL:

        while( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Take into account that there is no need to declare the variable `head1` as global. It is better to declare it inside the function `main`.

Also all the allocated memory should be freed before exiting the program.

Comment: tysm for your answer !! could you please explain me line - head = &(*head)->next   and what was wrong with *temp = (*temp)->next;

Comment: @Yogendra123 Due to this assignment struct node **temp = head; temp is a pointer to the original head of the list. So the expression *temp is the head and in this statement temp = (*temp)->next; the value of the head is changed that is head will point to the last node of the list for which the data member next is equal to NULL.